# ionic push notification not working in iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

when i send a notification through firebase for my ionic app(ios)..it doesn't display in ios..but it shows in xcode log.

i have completed all setting in xcode and apple developer account(like ios certificates)..even though not receiving in notification

**fcm.service code**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';  
import { UrlServiceProvider } from '../url-service/url-service';
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Injectable()
export class FcmServiceProvider {

 constructor(public http: Http,public urlService : UrlServiceProvider, 
private firebase: Firebase,
private afs: AngularFirestore,
private platform: Platform) {
console.log('Hello TokenServiceProvider Provider');
}


saveToken(credentials,token) {
var data = {};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    data = {
        'userid' : credentials,
        'devicetoken' : token,
        'usertype':'1'
    };
    console.log("Sirius Token Token Device : "+localStorage.getItem('devicetoken'));
    console.log("Sirius Save Device Token Inside : "+JSON.stringify(data));
    let apiUrl = this.urlService.apiUrl  + 'devicetoken';
    this.http.post(apiUrl,data)
      .subscribe(res => {
          console.log("Sirius Save Device Token Inside : "+JSON.stringify(res));
              console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));

         resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)));
      }, (err) => {
        console.log("Sirius Save Device Token : "+JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(err)));
        reject(err);
      });
});
}
```

**Xcode log**

[image]

Help me to fix this issue..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your app in foreground while debugging? You will not see the banner when in foreground by default.

Comment: i'm using usb debugger. in that also it won't work ah?? @MohammadrezaFarahani

Comment: That's fine. You should debug and test while your app is in background (or even terminated). Check if the notification banner appears in this state.

Comment: notification does not shows when the app in background @MohammadrezaFarahani

Comment: Have you added `remote-notification` to your config.xml file?

Comment: no i didn't add that...how to add remote-notification to config.xml @MohammadrezaFarahani

Comment: Could you post the structure of the payload that you send to FCM? 
Which plugin are you using to enable push notifications ?
How are you sending them ?

Comment: If you go into the iOS notification settings, do you see your app there, with notifications enabled?

Comment: In app setting, it does not shows a notification setting..@BRass